# Opening html file with query string

Tags: c#, html, wpf, process, query-string

Is it possible to load a local HTML file with a query string? I'm using Process.Start, but that fails because appending `?querystring=test` to the end of the filename makes it search for that.

```
Process.Start("page.html?querystring=test")
```

The code above results in a FileNotFound exception. I've tried using ProcessStartInfo and pass the query string as an argument, but that just loaded the normal page. Is this possible?

Comment: What browser are you using?

Comment: I'm using Firefox but I don't think this is a browser issue.

Comment: you just want to open the url ??

Comment: This page - http://www.dotnetperls.com/process-start - implies that this should work.

Comment: @Sohail Yes, with the query string.

Comment: @ChrisF - It works for remote URLs, but I'd like to open a local html file on the user's machine.

Comment: And how would a local file handle a query string?? If its on a local server then http://localhost/file.php?a=b. A plain html file cannot process a query string.

Comment: @user574632 - Javascript. It works fine when calling it from a browser.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not possible because query strings are a part of HTTP protocol and so they only work when a file is served from a web server. A local HTML file is simply read from the file system.

Comment: Seems like it's not possible then. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: @SSL - It seems possible. Check out the answer here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13550837/process-startlink-omits-part-of-the-link

Comment: @RV1987 - Thanks, I hadn't seen that post!

Comment: but... what if the file is running javascript which is trying to look for the "?" to use as the argument to the web page?  Is there something else that should be used instead? (btw despite the age of the question this *used* to work for me)