# Process.Start(link) omits part of the link

Tags: c#, hyperlink, process.start

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Opening html file with query string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13545871/opening-html-file-with-query-string)

I'm writing a simple console app using c# and I'm trying to open a local html file with "name" parameter. For now I'm using const url (For testing...):
"file:///D:/index.html?name=bob"

The code is simple:

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string link = @"file:///D:/index.html?name=bob";
            Process.Start(link);
        }
    }
```

But it opens the browser with the link: "file:///D:/index.html".
Do anyone knows why does it omit the 'name' parameter and how to fix it?

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe the browser is removing the parameter as part of a security policy?

Comment: Does '@"file:///D:/index.html&#063;name=bob";' work?

Comment: @CSharpie, No. I got an exception because it can't find file specified.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't mind binding to a specific browser (rather than the one defined in the system), this works:

```
Process.Start("iexplore.exe", @"file:///D:/index.html?name=bob")
```

Otherwise I'm guessing you could deduce the associated program (probably via the [registry](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa767914%28VS.85%29.aspx)) and employ the same technique.

Comment: Wow.It does work. Thanks.
Do you know why it emits it in the first way?
My default (and only) browser is Internet Explorer.

Comment: @kernelMode because `?` is not an allowed character in a filename - it is a "wildcard"...

Comment: I went over the reference source, and as far as I can tell it ultimately calls the Win32 `CreateProcessWithLogonW` function with the commandline as is (almost), so I believe this is Win32 behavior (rather than something specific to .NET's `Process` class). *EDIT* Yahia probably nailed it.

Comment: The URL is not a file name anyway, so ? being a file name wildcard does not come into play.

Comment: @usr it comes into play because under the hood it is basically a call to `CreateProcess...` and is thus filtered out...

Comment: @Yahia it does not call CreateProcess. It calls ShellExecute. CreateProcess does not know about file associations.

Comment: @usr did you check the reference source (.NET Framework)... although that could differ depending on framework version...

Comment: I'm using .NET 3.0, so according MSDN: "Starting a process by specifying its file name and arguments is similar to typing the file name and command-line arguments in the Run dialog box of the Windows Start menu." So I guess it make sense that the first method parse the link as a file and the second parse it as a link. BTW, there is an option to set `UseShellExecute` to True\False in the StartInfo property.