# Passing JSON Data From C# to Standalone Javascript File (No Web Server)

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, json, html

I'm trying to pass data (JSON) from a C# (winforms) application to a static html/javascript file that does some canvas drawing to present a graph based on details in the JSON object.  The html/javascript file runs in the browser only and does not require a web server.  I would like to keep from hosting the html file if possible.

Since there is no server involved, I'm assuming it's not possible to pass data via a 'get' or 'post'?

I've tried writing the JSON to a file on the user's pc, running a Process.Start() from the C# application (on the javascript file) to make it open in the browser, then having the page read the JSON data from the file.  This results in a "permission denied error".

Additionally, I found the following comment:
*"The HTML5 fileReader facility does allow you to process local files, but these MUST be selected by the user, you cannot go rooting about the users disk looking for files."*
From here: [How to open a local disk file with Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3582671/how-to-open-a-local-disk-file-with-javascript)

How can I get the data from my app to the javascript file without any user intervention?  Are there any other options?

Thanks in advance for any ideas / help.

**C# > Serialize the JSON, Write to File, Launch Javascript File...**

```
...
        string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(this);
        sendJson(json);
    }

    private void sendJson(string json)
    {
        Assembly assy = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
        string appRoot = Path.GetDirectoryName(assy.Location);
        string pathToCurveFile = string.Format("{0}\\{1}", appRoot, "WebPages\\curve.htm");
        string pathToJsonData = string.Format("{0}\\{1}", appRoot, "WebPages\\curveData.json");

        File.WriteAllText(pathToJsonData, json);
    }
```

**Javascript > Try to Read the JSON File When Page Loads**

```
function init() {
        var json;
        var dataFilePath = 'file://C:/Temp/curveData.json';

        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = function (e) { payload = reader.result; }
        reader.readAsText(dataFilePath);

        json = JSON.parse(payload);
```

Comment: You can try using the .net browser control and load the webpage in it, passing the data after the `#`, then get it in the js with window.location.hash.

Comment: How are you opening the html? A browser control from the winform? If so, you can add a JS event in that html and call it from C#. I can send you an example if you need it. Also you can load the page with parameters.

Comment: From C# I am using a Process.Start(somefile.htm).  The reason I stayed away from a browser control is because I am using HTML5 canvas and I didn't think the browser control would support that but, may need to research further.

Comment: Correct, it will use the IE engine of the host OS. Please check the following link to make that work with query string. 
`Process.Start("iexplore.exe", @"file:///D:/index.html?name=bob")`
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13550837/process-startlink-omits-part-of-the-link

Comment: You could also look at using [CefSharp](http://cefsharp.github.io/) to embed chromium within your app.

Comment: Please let us know if it worked for you or you found another way so another person with the same or a similar scenario can use this thread for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option is to write a JavaScript file instead of plain JSON, then just add a script-tag to your HTML-page and you have access to your JSON data.

Javascript to be written, e.g. `mydata.js`:

```
var myJSON = {.....};
```

In HTML you just include

```
<script src="mydata.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Now you can access `myJSON` from any script in your HTML-page.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

You best bet is to generate the whole HTML file:

1. Read markup from your static HTML file.
2. Inject `<script>` section where you have your your generated json data.
3. Enjoy.

Answer (score 0):

You can dynamically call c# methods from html page contained in webBrowser control. 
For example suppose you have a class like

```
[ComVisible(true)] // <== Needed
public class ScriptObject
{
    public string GetJSon()
    {
        return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new { a=1, b=2 });
        //not recommended way
        //return "{\"a\":1,\"b\":2}";
    }
}
```

You can call it's method in javascript like

```
string html =   "<html>" + 
                "<head>"+
                    "<meta http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible' content='IE=edge'>" +
                "</head>" + 
                "<script>" +
                  "var obj = JSON.parse(external.GetJSon());" +
                  "alert(obj.a)" +
                "</script>" + 
                "</html>";

webBrowser1.ObjectForScripting = new ScriptObject();
webBrowser1.DocumentText = html;
```

You can access the c# object in javascript using the *external* keyword.